# wmctrl - focus most recent window of an app

Tags: window-management, wmctrl

I've created some shortcuts mimicking the Unity's <kbd>Mod4</kbd> + <kbd>num</kbd> behavior.

```
wmctrl -xa Sublime || subl
```

What I don't like, is that once sublime is running, it always focuses the first opened window. I'd like to focus the last "focused" window. Same as in Unity. Is there a flag for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a very robust app switcher using `wmctrl`. Check my [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144498) and my [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/274231/44099).

This is the script to launch:

```
#!/bin/bash
app_name=$1
workspace_number=`wmctrl -d | grep '\*' | cut -d' ' -f 1`
win_list=`wmctrl -lx | grep $app_name | grep " $workspace_number " | awk '{print $1}'`


active_win_id=`xprop -root | grep '^_NET_ACTIVE_W' | awk -F'# 0x' '{print $2}' | awk -F', ' '{print $1}'`
if [ "$active_win_id" == "0" ]; then
    active_win_id=""
fi


# get next window to focus on, removing id active
switch_to=`echo $win_list | sed s/.*$active_win_id// | awk '{print $1}'`
# if the current window is the last in the list ... take the first one
if [ "$switch_to" == "" ];then
    switch_to=`echo $win_list | awk '{print $1}'`
fi


if [[ -n "${switch_to}" ]]
    then
        (wmctrl -ia "$switch_to") &
    else
        if [[ -n "$2" ]]
            then
                ($2) &
        fi
fi


exit 0
```

Comment: So, this doesn't go directly to the last-focused window, but instead lets you iterate through the application's windows in the order in which they were opened. Really nice script....(I'm using it).

Comment: Exactly. Glad you like it. I've made a whole minimal wmctrl tiling manager (aka a script) and hopefully will publish soon.

Answer (score 15):

This script does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

app=$1
workspace=$(wmctrl -d | grep '\*' | cut -d ' ' -f1)
win_list=$(wmctrl -lx | grep $app | grep " $workspace " | awk '{print $1}')

IDs=$(xprop -root|grep "^_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING" | tr "," " ")
IDs=(${IDs##*#})

for (( idx=${#IDs[@]}-1 ; idx>=0 ; idx-- )) ; do
    for i in $win_list; do
        if [ $((i)) = $((IDs[idx])) ]; then
            wmctrl -ia $i
            exit 0
        fi
    done
done

exit 1
```

EDIT: This script always focuses on the last focused window, as opposed to cycling through the windows in the order they were opened.

EDIT 2: I modified the script (turns out wmctrl and xprop use slightly different formats for displaying hexadecimal numbers).

EDIT 3: app name should be taken from the 3rd column of wmctrl -lx to avoid certain conflicts.

Comment: The question was already answered, providing an extra answer can be helpful but then explain why and what this is a better / different solution.

Comment: I added an explanation although the first line already says that this script does exactly what the OP asked for. The accepted solution, while useful, does not.

Comment: Nice script, does exactly what the OP asked for, it is strange the other answer is accepted. Anyway, is it possible to expand this script, so that it could also cycle windows of the same application in chronological focus order?

Comment: Do you mean for the loop to go in the reverse order? I haven't tried it but maybe `for (( idx=0 ; idx<${#IDs[@]} ; idx++ )) ; do` will do it.

Comment: No. The current version does not go through loop at all, it just brings the last active window. If there are other open windows of the same app, and if I run the script again, it will not cycle through them. What I am seeking for is to expand this version so that 1) it brings last active window of the app ($1) to foreground, if none of app's windows is currently active, 2) if one of app's windows is already active, bring previously active window of this app, etc.

Comment: I see. I don't think there's an easy fix for that. The problem is that when you focus on a window using this script, that changes the order of window IDs returned by `xprop`. So, if you want to cycle through windows of the same app, you'd need to save the initial list of IDs to disk and read from that. I see how this can be useful, but I haven't implemented it myself, because if I understood you correctly, this is close to what the current application switchers can already do. I'm referring to the command typically bound to Alt+\`.

Comment: Exactly. I've already implemented that in the script: upon condition that the active window is of class $1, just do:  xdotool type --delay 1 --clearmodifiers "clear" and xdotool key --clearmodifiers Alt+grave (imitate Alt+`).

Comment: Are you assuming here that _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING is in order of recent focus?

Comment: Yes, in my experience `_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING` is always ordered by recently opened.

Answer (score 4):

I made a combination of both previous answers which I find quite convenient. It enables to:

- set the focus to the most recently focused window of the app (answer of Raul Laasner) **if that window does not already have the focus**;
- otherwise, cycle to the next window of the app (answer of mreq);
- if there is no window of the app, open one (there is now an optional second argument which specifies the command to run in that case).

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  echo "Usage : $0 <window name> [<command to run if there is no window with that name>]"
  exit 1
fi

app_name=$1

workspace_number=`wmctrl -d | grep '\*' | cut -d' ' -f 1`
win_list=`wmctrl -lx | grep $app_name | grep " $workspace_number " | awk '{print $1}'`

# Get the id of the active window (i.e., window which has the focus)
active_win_id=`xprop -root | grep '^_NET_ACTIVE_W' | awk -F'# 0x' '{print $2}' | awk -F', ' '{print $1}'`
if [ "$active_win_id" == "0" ]; then
    active_win_id=""
fi

# If the window currently focused matches the first argument, seek the id of the next window in win_list which matches it
if [[ "$win_list" == *"$active_win_id"* ]]; then

    # Get next window to focus on 
    # (sed removes the focused window and the previous windows from the list)
    switch_to=`echo $win_list | sed s/.*$active_win_id// | awk '{print $1}'`

    # If the focused window is the last in the list, take the first one
    if [ "$switch_to" == "" ];then
        switch_to=`echo $win_list | awk '{print $1}'`
    fi

# If the currently focused window does not match the first argument
else

    # Get the list of all the windows which do
    win_list=$(wmctrl -lx | grep $app_name | awk '{print $1}')

    IDs=$(xprop -root|grep "^_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING" | tr "," " ")
    IDs=(${IDs##*#})

   # For each window in focus order
    for (( idx=${#IDs[@]}-1 ; idx>=0 ; idx-- )) ; do
        for i in $win_list; do

           # If the window matches the first argument, focus on it
            if [ $((i)) = $((IDs[idx])) ]; then
                wmctrl -ia $i
                exit 0
            fi
        done
    done
fi

# If a window to focus on has been found, focus on it
if [[ -n "${switch_to}" ]]
then
    (wmctrl -ia "$switch_to") &

# If there is no window which matches the first argument
else

    # If there is a second argument which specifies a command to run, run it
    if [[ -n "$2" ]]
    then
        ($2) &
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

Example of usages:

```
focus_window.sh vlc vlc
focus_window.sh gnome-control-center gnome-control-center
focus_window.sh gnome-terminal gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for! I think this should be built into gnome so that you can easily assign shortcuts for the most used programs. Note that the cycling is restricted to the current desktop unless there are now matching windows on that desktop - that is perfect imo.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on Wayland, does anyone have a version which is Wayland compatible? I want exactly the functionality/features of this script, working with it for about three years now, thanks again!

Comment: You can first check if you have wmctrl installed and if the following commands work `wmctrl -lx` to get the windows id and `wmctrl -ia <ID>` to focus on the window of id <ID>. Otherwise, you can execute the script in a console and see the output or try each line one by one and see if the output is what is expected.

Comment: I know that but wmctrl does not work with Wayland windows.

Answer (score 0):

Late for the answer, but managed to do it work gracefully, in my case, using Firefox:

`/usr/lib/firefox/firefox && sleep 0.5 &&  wmctrl -ia $(wmctrl -l Firefox | grep "Mozilla Firefox" | sort -r | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1)`

Explanation:

`/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` - Opens firefox

`sleep 0.5` - Gives some time for the window to open

`wmctrl -ia` - Focus on a specific window ID

`$(wmctrl -l Firefox | grep "Mozilla Firefox" | sort -r | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1)` - Gets the last window ID, which in my case, is open on the homepage, so its name is "Mozilla Firefox".